# How to add hatches to boxplots with sns.boxplot or sns.catplot

Tags: python, seaborn, data-visualization, boxplot, catplot

I need to add hatches to a categorical box plot.
What I have is this:
[image]

What I need is something like this (with the median lines):

[image]

And what I have tried is this code:

```
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, kind="box")
bars = g.axes[0][0].patches
hatches=['//','..','xx','//','..','xx','//','..','xx']
for pat,bar in zip(hatches,bars):
    bar.set_hatch(pat)
```

That only generates the first figure. The idea for lines 3-6 comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64340226/plot-a-stacked-bar-plot-in-seaborn-with-hatching). But the idea to get `axes[0][0]` in line 3 comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250699/how-to-add-percentages-on-top-of-bars-in-seaborn-facetgrid).

Because FacetGrids don't have attributes like patches or containers, it makes it harder to adapt the answers about hatches in individual plots to categorical plots, so I couldn't figure it out.

### Other reviewed questions that don't work:

- [Face pattern for boxes in boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28740234/7758804)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Iterate through each subplot / FacetGrid with `for ax in g.axes.flat:`.
2. `ax.patches` contains `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` and `matplotlib.patches.PathPatch`, so the correct ones must be used.

- Caveat: all hues must appear for each group in each Facet, otherwise the `patches` and `hatches` will not match.

  - In this case, manual or conditional code will probably be required to correctly determine `h`, so `zip(patches, h)` works.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

# load test data
exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")

# plot
g = sns.catplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise, col='diet', kind="box")

# hatches must equal the number of hues (3 in this case)
hatches = ['//', '..', 'xx']

# iterate through each subplot / Facet
for ax in g.axes.flat:

    # select the correct patches
    patches = [patch for patch in ax.patches if type(patch) == mpl.patches.PathPatch]
    # the number of patches should be evenly divisible by the number of hatches
    h = hatches * (len(patches) // len(hatches))
    # iterate through the patches for each subplot
    for patch, hatch in zip(patches, h):
        patch.set_hatch(hatch)
        fc = patch.get_facecolor()
        patch.set_edgecolor(fc)
        patch.set_facecolor('none')
```

[image]

- Add the following, to change the legend.

```py
for lp, hatch in zip(g.legend.get_patches(), hatches):
    lp.set_hatch(hatch)
    fc = lp.get_facecolor()
    lp.set_edgecolor(fc)
    lp.set_facecolor('none')
```

[image]

---

- If only using the axes-level `sns.boxplot`, there's no need to iterate through multiple axes.

```py
ax = sns.boxplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)

# select the correct patches
patches = [patch for patch in ax.patches if type(patch) == mpl.patches.PathPatch]
# the number of patches should be evenly divisible by the number of hatches
h = hatches * (len(patches) // len(hatches))
# iterate through the patches for each subplot
for patch, hatch in zip(patches, h):
    patch.set_hatch(hatch)
    fc = patch.get_facecolor()
    patch.set_edgecolor(fc)
    patch.set_facecolor('none')

l = ax.legend()
    
for lp, hatch in zip(l.get_patches(), hatches):
    lp.set_hatch(hatch)
    fc = lp.get_facecolor()
    lp.set_edgecolor(fc)
    lp.set_facecolor('none')
```

[image]

---

- To keep the facecolor of the box plots:

  1. Remove `patch.set_facecolor('none')`
  2. Set the edgecolor as `'k'` (black) instead of `fc`, `patch.set_edgecolor('k')`.

  - Applies to the `sns.catplot` code too.

```py
ax = sns.boxplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)

# select the correct patches
patches = [patch for patch in ax.patches if type(patch) == mpl.patches.PathPatch]
# the number of patches should be evenly divisible by the number of hatches
h = hatches * (len(patches) // len(hatches))
# iterate through the patches for each subplot
for patch, hatch in zip(patches, h):
    patch.set_hatch(hatch)
    patch.set_edgecolor('k')
    
l = ax.legend()
    
for lp, hatch in zip(l.get_patches(), hatches):
    lp.set_hatch(hatch)
    lp.set_edgecolor('k')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @trenton-mckinney did not work for the box plot case.
My environment uses python 3.6.12, pandas 1.1.5, matplotlib 3.3.4, seaborn 0.11.2.

As an alternative, we can use the `ax.artists` element of the box plot axes to manually apply hatches to the individual box elements. Here's the updated code snippet:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

exercise = sns.load_dataset("exercise")
ax = sns.boxplot(x="time", y="pulse", hue="kind", data=exercise)
hatches = ['//', '..', 'xx']
for i, artist in enumerate(ax.artists):
    artist.set_hatch(hatches[i % len(hatches)])

l = ax.legend()
for lp, hatch in zip(l.get_patches(), hatches):
    lp.set_hatch(hatch)
    lp.set_edgecolor('k')
```

[image]