# How can I add hatching for specific bars in sns.catplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot

I use seaborn to make a categorical barplot of a df containing Pearson correlation R-values for 17 vegetation classes, 3 carbon species and 4 regions. I try to recreate a smaller sample df here:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({

    'veg class':12*['Tree bl dc','Shrubland','Grassland'],
    'Pearson R':np.random.uniform(0,1, 36),
    'Pearson p':np.random.uniform(0,0.1, 36),
    'carbon':4*['CO2','CO2','CO2', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO', 'CO2 corr', 'CO2 corr', 'CO2 corr'],
    'spatial':9*['SH'] + 9*['larger AU region'] + 9*['AU'] + 9*['SE-AU'] 

    })

#In my original df, the number of vegetation classes where R-values are
#available is not the same for all spatial scales, so I drop random rows
#to make it more similar:
df.drop([11,14,17,20,23,26,28,29,31,32,34,35], inplace=True)

#I added colums indicating where hatching should be
#boolean:
df['significant'] = 1
df.loc[df['Pearson p'] > 0.05, 'significant'] = 0
#string:
df['hatch'] = ''
df.loc[df['Pearson p'] > 0.05, 'hatch'] = 'x'

df.head()
```

This is my plotting routine:

```
sns.set(font_scale=2.1)

#Draw a nested barplot by veg class
g = sns.catplot(
data=df, kind="bar", row="spatial",
x="veg class", y="Pearson R", hue="carbon",
    ci=None, palette="YlOrBr", aspect=5
    )

g.despine(left=True)
g.set_titles("{row_name}")
g.set_axis_labels("", "Pearson R")
g.set(xlabel=None)
g.legend.set_title("")
g.set_xticklabels(rotation = 60)
```

(The plot looks as follows: [seaborn categorical barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGAdA.png))

The plot is exactly how I would like it, except that now I would like to add hatching (or any kind of distinction) for all bars where the Pearson R value is insignificant, i.e. where the p value is larger than 0.05. I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72656861/how-to-add-hatches-to-boxplots-with-sns-boxplot-or-sns-catplot) entry, but my problem differs from this, as the plots that should be hatched are not in repetitive order.

Any hints will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the height of individual bars and hatching, we get a container for each graph unit, get the height of that individual container, determine it with a specified threshold, and then set the hatching and color. Please add the following code at the end.

```
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    for k in range(len(ax.containers)):
        h = ax.patches[k].get_height()
        if h >= 0.8:
            ax.patches[k].set_hatch('*')
            ax.patches[k].set_edgecolor('k')
```

[image]

Edit: The data has been updated to match the actual data, and the code has been modified accordingly. Also, the logic is conditional on the value of the hatching column.

```
for i,ax in enumerate(g.axes.flat):
    s = ax.get_title()
    dff = df.query('spatial == @s')
    dff = dff.sort_values('veg class', ascending=False)
    ha = dff['hatch'].tolist()
    p = dff['Pearson R'].tolist()
    print(ha)
    for k in range(len(dff)):
        if ha[k] == 'x':
            ax.patches[k].set_hatch('*')
            ax.patches[k].set_edgecolor('k')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing your idea! However, the significance is not determined by the R value itself, but by the p value (separate column in the df -> R value is significant where p value < 0.05). Thus relating the hatch to the bar height is not what I want.

Comment: I think the method of judging from the height of the graph is also useful, so I left it and added code to judge from the value of the data frame.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want, but if I add it to my plotting routine, the following error message pops up: "list index out of range" (relating to p[k], I think). I assume this might happen because in my original df, the four different spatial scales do not contain the same number of R-values (some vegetation classes do not exist on the smaller scales). So the number of vegetation classes with R-values is 17 for "SH", 15 for "larger AU region", and 14 for both "AU" and "SAU"...

Comment: I am creating the code based on the data presented, so it may be different with actual data. Can you provide sample data with the same structure as the actual data?

Comment: Absolutely. I just added a line where I drop random rows to make it more similar to my original df. I hope this helps!

Comment: What do the four blanks refer to? When I run the code, it creates a list of hatching by graph. I think the hatching matches that list. And am I referring to the hatching columns in the wrong way?

Comment: The following code is used for sorting. `dff = dff.sort_values('veg class', ascending=False)` Try this: `print(dff)`

Comment: I achieved my goal with this answer and a tiny adaptation: I removed  the line ```dff = dff.sort_values('veg class', ascending=False)```, as this yielded hatching of the bars in the wrong order. Thank you so much solving my problem in no time!